# hierarchy problems changing paragraph style from css

Tags: css, hover

I want to change paragraph style

from CSS using hover on different element without default

style overwriting it.
HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div class="a">AAAA</div>

    <div class ="b">
      <div class ="sub_b">
            <p>BBBB</p></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
    color: red;
}
p {
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

.a:hover ~ .b {
    background-color: blue;
    color: orange;
}
```

I want to change color of font BBBB to orange, when hovering over AAAA. The hovering happens, BBBB style fonts gets command for changing background-color and font color, but font color is overwritten by default paragraph P style.
I am not able to change much of the html hierarchy. What can I do from CSS only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css is working fine!
Just select the `<p>` inside of your `class="b"`

Like this:

```
.a:hover ~ .b p {
    color: orange;
}
```

```css
.a {
    color: red;
}
p {
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

.a:hover ~ .b {
    background-color: blue;
    color: orange;
}

.a:hover ~ .b p {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

    <div class="a">AAAA</div>

    <div class ="b">
      <div class ="sub_b">
            <p>BBBB</p></div>
      </div>
</div>
```